# Is there a way to hit my local API with http from my app on an android phone device

Tags: angular2-nativescript

I have been having a problem trying to hit my local API with my NativeScript app. I have set up my API to use my IP address 198.168.1 and a port number, but I get an error of clearText java error. I have added allow clearText to true in the manifest and I have tried to set up a network security config with no prevail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emulator API Path:- http://10.0.2.2:5000.
Like Your API Local Path Is  http://198.168.1:5000/api Then Replace With http://10.0.2.2:5000/api And Port Address Is Same Like As Your Local API Port.